why is RSS 5x the size of heap Total, Array buffer and External combined?
i would like to monitor my applications memory usage.
most of the APM tools provide insights to heap usage. which according to my understanding is normal in my case.memory allocation
i want to know why what is going on and how is this allocated memory being utilized.
i have tried using Datadog, PM2 monit and elastic observability. but none can provide the information i am looking for.
